# Convergence of random variable

Tags: distributions, convergence

Suppose we have a random variable $Y^n(x)$ which depends on $x\in[0,1]$, and this $Y^n(x)$ converges in probability to $Y(x)$ which is a constant. Let a bounded and continuous function $f$ be given.

Then for all $x\in[0,1]$, we have $\mathbb E[f(Y^n(x))]\rightarrow f(Y(x))$ by Portmanteau lemma.

My question is: For an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, can we find a universal $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $\mathbb E[f(Y^n(x))]$ lies within $\epsilon$ balls each of which centered at $f(Y(x))$ for all $n\geq N$ and for all $x\in[0,1]$?

Comment: Are you sure you have formulated your question as you intended? In general, you cannot find an $n$ for which this is true even for a *single* $x$! Suppose, for instance, that $Y^n(x)$ has a Normal$(0, 1/n)$ distribution. It converges in probability to $Y(x)=0$, but for *all* natural numbers $n$ and *any* $\epsilon\gt 0$, $\Pr(|Y^n(x)-0| \gt \epsilon)$ is never zero.

Comment: @whuber Oh, I forgot to mention about the function part. Thank you for pointing that out and for your example.

Comment: OK. Unfortunately you haven't stated anything that gives you control over the rate at which $Y^n(x)$ converges.  Suppose, for instance, $X$ has a standard Normal distribution and that $Y^n(x)=Xn^{-x}$ for $x\gt 0$, $Y^n(0)=0$. All the $Y^n(x)$ converge in probability to $0$, but what could $N$ possibly be?

Comment: I see. So you mean without any information about rate of convergence, we can't generally tell anything about the universal $N$, right?